# GitHub - Shared Network Drive Repo

Tags: git, github, network-drive

HI guys I am a newbie to git but we are trying to use it in the office for tracking changes to large web projects.

We have the website files for a large site set on a shared network drive, here is my current process and the problems I am facing!

I am on Windows 10 and using the git command line interface.

I cd to this website directory on our shared drive and do the following:

```
$ cd /x/Clients/ClientA/Website/
$ git init
$ git status
$ git add --all
$ git commit -m "Initial Commit"
```

I then cd to my desktop and clone a local version:

```
$ cd /c/Users/Account/Desktop/
$ git clone /x/Clients/ClientA/Website/
```

This clones perfectly, I now change a file using Atom inside my Desktop/Website/ folder and save it.

I then commit those changes and try to push them back to my shared drive:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   index.html

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git add --all

$ git commit -m "Edited file"
[master 76782c6] Edited file
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+)

$ git push
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 922 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 11 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Checking connectivity: 11, done.
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: the work tree to HEAD.
remote:
remote: You can set the 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable
remote: to 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: other way.
remote:
remote: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To X:/Clients/ClientA/Website/
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'X:/Clients/ClientA/Website/'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how I can get it set up so that multiple people in the office can clone and push to that one place on the network drive successfully?

Thanks!

Comment: Reading Assignment: [4.1 Git on the Server - The Protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols)

Comment: Thank you for the link I will definitely give it a read!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a common practice to a non-bare repository,
and as the error message tells,
this is not enabled by default.
I recommend to use a *bare* repository instead, without a working tree.

You can create a bare repository from the existing `/x/Clients/ClientA/Website/` like this:

```
git clone /x/Clients/ClientA/Website --bare /x/Clients/ClientA/Website.git
```

After this, you can clone from `/x/Clients/ClientA/Website.git` and you can push to it.
It cannot have a working tree though.

If, for example, you want to have a working tree always up to date with `master`,
you could create a dedicated clone for that from `/x/Clients/ClientA/Website.git`, and you could setup a post-commit hook in `/x/Clients/ClientA/Website.git` to trigger `git pull` in the dedicated clone.

Comment: This is factually incorrect.  You *can* push to a non-bare repo, and with the right configuration you can even push to the branch that's checked out.  It is correct that the default remote *usually* is a bare repo

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger fair enough, I reworded that part.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, so what is the downfall of not having a working tree? I just need changes to those files tracked when everyone is making changes that is the only purpose for this so are branches not necessary?

Comment: Ok so I cloned that folder on the X:/ drive to Website.git. I then cloned that to my desktop, made changes and pushed them back successfully. My changes are tracked in Website.git which is great, but where are the physical files i have pushed to that bare repo?

Comment: @KiwisTasteGood the "downside" of the bare repo is that it has no physical files. To have the physical files, you need a clone. To update the physical files in a clone after somebody else pushed to `master`, you have to pull. As usual when working with any Git repo. As for branches, you can have branches in this repo just like any Git repo. There's nothing really special about this repo.

Comment: @janos Ah ok so if I make changes and push to the bare repo, it just adds my changes into the git files? So if I wanted to then upload my changes to a live site I would do a pull to make sure my files are up to date and then upload from my local copy via FTP?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144061/discussion-between-kiwistastegood-and-janos).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to push on a remote that has a "working tree" and right now, on that repo, the branch that is checked out is the one you are trying to push into. Think of it the other way around: You are working on branch X and someone else tries to push into your branch X. You would like git to restrict it because it would be like pulling a rug from under your feet, right? Well, that's it.